# Click not working on widgets added by user with in android app

Tags: android, widget

I'm letting user to select the widget from the list of widgets by opening the widgets intent

```
 public void initAppWidget() {
    try {
        mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        mAppWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(this, Constants.APPWIDGET_HOST_ID);

    } catch
            (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void selectWidget() {
    int appWidgetId = mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
    pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, Constants.SELECT_APPWIDGET);
}
```

onActivityResult will be called when user selects the widget from the list

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {

        case Constants.SELECT_APPWIDGET:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                configureWidget(data);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
                int appWidgetId = data.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
                if (appWidgetId != -1) {
                    mAppWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(appWidgetId);
                }
            }
            break;

        case Constants.REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                createWidget(data);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
                int appWidgetId = data.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
                if (appWidgetId != -1) {
                    mAppWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(appWidgetId);
                }
            }

            break;
    }
}

 public void configureWidget(Intent data) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    int appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);

    if (appWidgetInfo.configure != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE);
        intent.setComponent(appWidgetInfo.configure);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET);
    } else {
        createWidget(data);
    }
}
```

Finally createWidget function adds the widget view to the linear layout

```
public void createWidget(Intent data) {
    int appWidgetId = data.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);

    AppWidgetHostView hostView = mAppWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
    hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
    hostView.setId(id);
    ll_widgets_list.addView(hostView);
    id++;
}
```

But some widgets are not taking click e.g. Analog clock . Some widgets like google drive contains other views in it which are clickable and working fine. Widget is not updating whenever user performs any action through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mAppWidgetHost.startListening();
```

This line was missing from the initAppWidget() function which listens the widget changes.